# Cirq.simulate expectation value of a Hamiltonian

Tags: programming, hamiltonian-simulation, cirq

I want to simulate the final state of an ansatz in cirq using simulate.
Now I want to calculate the expectation value of a Hamiltonian.

How do I do this? I can only find simulator.run examples in cirq. But I want to access the wavefunction and therefore would need simulator.simulate.

Is there a function in cirq I can use or how could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the wavefunction from `cirq.final_state_vector(circuit)`. Then you can define your observable as an instance of `cirq.PauliSum`, on which you will be able to use the `expectation_from_state_vector()` method to get the expectation value.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I have been doing so far, but I'd like to access the wavefunction by cirq.simulator.simulate because the other option takes very long to compute and I'd like to use a gpu simulator or similar to speed things up

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `cirq.simulator.simulate`? `cirq.final_state_vector` uses `cirq.Simulator`. It does get slow after a certain number of qubits though. Alternatively you can use qsim and qsimcirq - however, the step to calculate the expectation value based on the wave function will be still on the slower side today, we have an issue open for delegating expectation value calculation to the simulator: https://github.com/quantumlib/Cirq/issues/3492. I'd still recommend giving qsim a go!

Comment: I meant somethink like here: https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/docs/simulation.html
e.g.
`import numpy as np
circuit = cirq.Circuit()
circuit.append(basic_circuit(False))
result = simulator.simulate(circuit, qubit_order=[q0, q1])
print(np.around(result.final_state, 3))
`

Comment: Or can I specify the simulator before using `cirq.final_state_vector(circuit)` or `cirq.final_density_matrix(circuit)` ?
Up to now I just used it without specifying anything

Comment: You won't be able to define the simultor in cirq.final_state_vector and final_density_matrix. I'm still not sure what you are asking for. 
`cirq.Simulator` provides the final state vector as you described, by using `simulator.simulate()` and then the `result.final_state` has it. Then you can pass that state vector to a PauliSum's `expectation_from_*` method to get the expectation value.